# Simple Ring Question

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity.  Why does $(-1)(a) = -a$?

This should be true if and only if $a + (-1)(a) = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the distributive law together with the properties of $1$,

$$a + (-1)a = 1a + (-1)a = (1 + (-1))a = 0a = 0$$

---

And if you haven't proven that $0a = 0$, try considering $0 = 0 + 0$ and distributing appropriately.

Comment: ..and assuming one already knows thawt $\;0\cdot a=0\;$ in any ring...+1

Comment: @DonAntonio Good point.